# Serialising CompletableFuture bytecode

Tags: java, serialization, lambda, java-8, completable-future

I would like to create a `CompletableFuture` chain, serialize it to disk as bytecode/params, and run it again at some point in the future. For example:

```
CompletableFuture<String> chain = new CompletableFuture<String>();

CompletableFuture<String> pos = chain;
for (int ii = 0; ii < 4; ++ii) {
    final int val = ii;
    pos = pos.thenApply( (s)->{ return s+" plus"+val;} );
}
pos = pos.thenApply( (s)->{ return "The final answer is "+s;} );

saveDisk( "chaindata.dat", chain, pos );
/////
// at some time in the future, perhaps in another program
Pair<CompletableFuture<String>,CompletableFuture<String>> newChain = loadFrom( "chaindata.dat" );
newChain.getA().complete("Hello");
String result = newChain.getB().get(); // should get hello with all post processing
// result==The final answer is Hello plus0 plus1 plus2 plus3
```

The tricky thing with this of course is, even if the bytecode is stored in the current class file (retrievable with `Class.getResource()`), I need the final  variables set up in the chain to also be persisted.
(see the for loop above `final int var = ii;` )

My goal in the future really is to run the chain on a slave process that has most of the same class files (but not the class file that created the chain)
I would write the bytecode/data, reload it on the slave process, and run it.

As mentioned, I believe the final vars created in the loop at instantiation time are the tricky part of this. ie.
`pos = pos.thenApply( (s)->{ return s+" plus"+`**`val`**`;} );`

Does anyone have a suggestion how to accomplish this?

Comment: You don't have much there. I'm thinking that the only onlythings your missing are a competent reasoning for the program, itself. I'm lost on the dialog and I can only see your for is hard to read. Should be <=3. I suppose. Is there some part here that hangs? Are wondering which file to import?

Comment: The for loop was a example program for descriptive purposes.  The eventual goal is to ship a completablefuture chain to a slave process, and do the processing there.  This would be part of a remoting lib.
As a side note, I already have the remote proxy classloader working.  I'm stuck at providing remotely runnable CompleteableFutures.

Comment: I think then, you're asking us to give you some hints on getting the information out and back again. In that case, you should be listening to your own advice. You may not hear that much here, but this time I think you already had the answer.

Comment: Made some edits to the original question to make it a bit clearer.
pos = pos.thenApply( (s)->{ return s+" plus"+val;} );
I don't think val (0...3) is stored in the bytecode, and I don't know how to get it out any other way.  Each item added to the chain has its own value of val.

Comment: I still think you're prpbably doing it right.

Comment: It's a dark path....
http://cr.openjdk.java.net/~briangoetz/lambda/lambda-translation.html

Answer (score 2):

A warning first, from [the Lambda Expressions tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html#serialization):

> You can [serialize](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jndi/objects/serial.html) a lambda expression if its target type and its captured arguments are serializable. However, like [inner classes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html#serialization), **the serialization of lambda expressions is strongly discouraged**.

(emphasis is mine)

The problem with this requirement is that `CompletableFuture` is not `Serializable`, and extending it to be so would require you to duplicate a lot of code from `CompletableFuture` – as you need to override a lot of methods (like `thenApply()`) to make them return your new serializable type.

What can be done, however, is serializing the chain of operations that you want to do. Since it is basically a function that transforms a `CompletableFuture` into another one, the easiest would be to defined a `SerializableFunction` type:

```
private interface SerializableFunction<T, R> extends Serializable {
    R apply(T t);

    default <V> SerializableFunction<T, V> andThen(SerializableFunction<? super R, ? extends V> after) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(after);
        return (T t) -> after.apply(apply(t));
    }
}
```

Note: I explicitly chose not to extend `Function` because the `andThen()` argument is not the same (so it wouldn't be an override), and you need the `andThen()` argument to be serializable for the returned lambda to be serializable as well (as per the warning above).

You can then create your chain by wrapping all `CompletableFuture` calls in lambda expressions:

```
private static SerializableFunction<CompletableFuture<String>, CompletableFuture<String>> createChain() {
    SerializableFunction<CompletableFuture<String>, CompletableFuture<String>> result = c -> c;
    for (int ii = 0; ii < 4; ++ii) {
        final int val = ii;
        result = result.andThen(pos -> pos.thenApply(s -> s + " plus" + val));
    }
    return result.andThen(pos -> pos.thenApply(s -> "The final answer is " + s));
}
```

and serialize it as desired:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(baos);
oos.writeObject(createChain());
oos.close();

ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(baos.toByteArray());
ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(bais);
SerializableFunction<CompletableFuture<String>, CompletableFuture<String>> chain =
        (SerializableFunction<CompletableFuture<String>, CompletableFuture<String>>) ois.readObject();

CompletableFuture<String> future = new CompletableFuture<>();
CompletableFuture<String> newChain = chain.apply(future);
newChain.thenAccept(System.out::println);
future.complete("Hello");
```

Output:

> The final answer is Hello plus0 plus1 plus2 plus3

Note that for this to work properly, the captured variables are indeed serialized (this is handled by [`SerilizedLambda`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/invoke/SerializedLambda.html)) but the unserializing JVM still need to have the lambda code itself, in a compatible version.

Taking this into account, it might be better to represent your chain of operations in a dedicated structure, and process that structure to rebuild the chain remotely.